# Is it possible to use Double pole 30amp breaker switch as a single pole 30amp breaker

Tags: electrical-panel

Can I use a double pole 30amp breaker as a 1 pole 30amp breaker? I need to wire a 30amp plug in for RV, I have an un used 2 pole breaker but need a 1 pole 30amp breaker.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A double pole is just 2 breakers together so that it should never be switched on only one side, but if you connect your wire to just 1 side then only 1 line is being controlled by the breaker.

Comment: Concur, I don't see a protection problem.  In fact I've seen this done by municipal electricians who are the electrical inspectors.